# .NET, SQL Server, NHibernate and high-precision decimals

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sql-server-2012, bigdecimal

I need to use decimal values with high precision - for instance, SQL Server 2012 [allows for up to 38 digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).

This is more precision than what `System.Decimal` supports ([28-29 significant digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Let's assume I use a certain implementation of `BigDecimal` to represent this on the CLR side that supports any needed constructor (e.g. from a string representation of the number).

The values are stored in the SQL Server database using the appropriate SQL Server `decimal` type.

I'm using NHibernate for ORM. I'm trying to create an [`IUserType`](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/10/15/mapping-different-types-iusertype.aspx) implementation that converts from the DB representation to the `BigDecimal` representation.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to do this without the use of an intermediate `System.Decimal` which would truncate data.

```
public virtual object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
{
    // ??
    object objValue = NHibernateUtil.Decimal.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);
    //objValue is already a System.Decimal

    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(objValue))
    {
        return new BigDecimal(objValue.ToString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Update:

In the Java counterpart, I can see a special Hibernate DbType for this exact use case: [`org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/BigDecimalType.html)

I'm starting to wonder if this is a limitation of the underlying ADO.NET layer - it also has no [defined `DbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx) appropriate for m use case, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call NHibernateUtil.Decimal.NullSafeGet(). Instead you should use methods available on the IDataReader to get the value.

If you use e.g. GetValue() on the reader, by the [type mapping table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx) it looks like you will get an instance of [System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal.aspx).

Then you will have to figure out how to convert the value to your BigDecimal.

Comment: I can't get this to work. getValue() tries to return a decimal which throws an overflow exception and it's not a SQLDataReader so I can't call .getSqlDecimal(). Any thoughts?

Comment: @Stu Are you using Oracle and should be using their types with larger precision?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. The IDataReader that I'm getting is an  NHybridDataReader.

Comment: @Stu Experiment with the Target property on  NHybridDataReader.

Comment: Ah, thanks I'll give that a look. I actually changed the binding to use a SQL convert and truncate the value. It's not ideal but it'll work for the current requirements while a better solution is sought. Thanks